# extract words or characters from expression in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know how to extract words or characters from expression in JavaScript or jquery.

For example

```
 if a expression is (3.14*radius*radius)
```

result should be `"radius", "radius"`

```
if a expression is (width*length)
```

result should be `"width", "length"`

```
same if a expression is 3.14/radius*(length)/yaxis
```

result should be `"radius", "length", "yaxis"`

I have tried different regular expressions on stackoverflow and google but I can't find any. How can I do that?

Comment: Please include at least some attempt of your own in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a simple regular expression:

```
var tokens = yourString.match(/[a-z]+/g);
```

Comment: @Ahmad You didn't take time to correctly format your question. You probably didn't search before asking.

Comment: @Ahmad, even you didn't try, didn't present what have you tried! its because of that i belief. whenever you post a question, you need to mention your tried code as well.

Comment: i have tried different regular expressions from stackoverflow and search it on google, but unfortunately i could'nt find, but this is very disappointed to ask question, my all reputation is lost.

Comment: @Ahmad You didn't lose much. Edit your question with a correct formatting (at least the code) and I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: I improved it and removed the downvote. Do it right from the start and your next questions should be better received ;)